# W10 Computers can't access Windows Server 2008 Shared Folders

Tags: windows, networking, shared-folders

I have a server with "Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise" Installed, it is not in a domain, it's a workgroup.

This server has several shared folders, a few days ago Win 10 computers can't access these shared folders (All 15 pc).

[image]

***Just computers with Windows 7, and other servers similar to this (WinServer2008) can access these shared folders with no problem.***

This is what I have done so far:

- Restarted the server.
- Restarted my HP Switch.
- All the 15 pcs can ping the server (192.168.100.3), can RDP, with no problems.
- Disabled A/V and Firewall on server.
- The shared folders have not been changed at all.
- I have a few SQL Databases running with no problem.
- Tried using the IP and/or UNC path.
- I have checked for malware, found nothing.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

Additional Information:

- Server and PC are in the same network (connected to tha same switch), both using a static IP.
- No firewall between them.
- I have enabled/disabled Netbios over TCP/IP, server and client, no luck.
- I have installed WireShark to analyze 192.168.100.3 traffic and determine the problem

This is a result from a Win 10 PC, I really don't undestand the errors.

Any Ideas?

[image: From Win7 PC]

---

### **UPDATE 05/03/2017**

I had no luck with this problem, I will have to re-install Windows Server from scratch.

Thanks to everybody for your time and help...

Comment: What happens when you try to access the shares?  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: When I type \\192.168.100.3\ on windows explorer I get this error:   Windows cannot access \\192.168.100.3 Check the spelling ot the name, Otherwise, the might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems. click Diagnose.  Error code: 0X80070035 The network path was not found.

Comment: I just solved a very similar problem. I can access the shares but i can't transfer any files. Are these shares on a different vlan than the rest? do you have a hardware firewall anywhere in between? My issue was the IPS  of the Firewall was blocking the transfer, apparently win10 and 7 do something different. I suggest running a wireshark capture and see if the connection is being rejected by the server or something else on the network

Comment: #acme64, All computers are in a same network, connected to the same switch, using static IP. So no firewall between them

Comment: Have you checked for a time skew? Also, have you tried disabling the built-in firewalls on both systems, just to eliminate that as the issue? Running any AV on either system and if so, tried disabling it too?

Comment: @MagnaVis... Firewall is disabled on both ends, A/V has been disabled on the server for testing. I'm doing an AV scan on server, I'll let you know... I have never heard of "time skew" let me get into it..

Comment: I'm assuming your server requires credentials (username/password) to connect to the share, right?  I've noticed that Windows 10 computers will not connect to a file share unless the other side requires a password.

Just a thought.

Comment: @ServiceManager Yes, credentials are required to connect to the share, "Password Protected Sharing" is turned ON... all of the users are registered on the server. I will try with one computer with win10 that isn't registered to se what happens.

Comment: @ServiceManager Same error

Comment: @MagnaVis AV scan found nothing

Answer (score 0):

Verify your DHCP with option 43 to send NetBIOS over TCP/IP. if it is disabled, enable it. if it is enabled, disable, save and than enable and save the config

A lot problems with 0X80070035 are related to NETBIOS

Comment: #TomEus, I already did that on the server side and on the client side. It was Set as Default, changed to Enable and to Disable. Didn't work